# GAS: Range Protection?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I've looked everywhere and it seems that GAS hasn't caught up with Google Spreadsheet. Is there a brute force method  for setting protection on certain ranges in a sheet..? (And making a protected sheet with all the formulas and referring to them won't help me.)

I found this through google: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1721

I even commented at the bottom. (More of a complaint than anything useful.) But the guy above me there posted this code:

```
//Function to Protect Target Sheet
function ProtectTargetSheet() {

      //Enter ID for each Worksheet
      var IDs = ["Sheeet_1", "Sheet_2"]

      //Enter Page to protect, in order of WorkSheets
      var Sheet_names = ["Page_1", "Page_2"]
      
      //For each sheet in the array
      for ( i = 0; i < IDs.length; i ++) {
      
        //id of sheet
        var sheet = IDs[i]
        
        //activate dedicated sheet
        var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet)
        
        //Find last row and column for each sheet
        var LastRow = ActiveSheet.getSheetByName(Sheet_names[i]).getLastRow();
        var LastCol = ActiveSheet.getSheetByName(Sheet_names[i]).getLastColumn();
        
        //Name of protectSheet
        var Name = "Protect_Sheet";
        
        //Range for Protection
        var Named_Range = ActiveSheet.getSheetByName(Sheet_names[i]).getRange(1, 1, LastRow, LastCol);
        
        //Impletment Protect Range
        var protected_Range = ActiveSheet.setNamedRange(Name, Named_Range);
      }
}
```

I don't see how this can work to give protection to a range when shared. It seems that it would just create a Named Range. He does say to set the permissions manually first. But I can't figure what exactly he meant.

Anyways, I was hoping that someone had found a way by now to do this until Google syncs GAS with its counterpart.

My wish is to, through 100% code, select a range in a sheet, within a spreadsheet, and make it so that when I share this whole spreadsheet to a person, that he or she can't edit that range. There will be other parts in that sheet that they have to be able to edit. Just not that range. It is easy to do this manually, but when having to create 100s of spreadsheets, it would be help to be able to do this through GAS.

Comment: Do these 100s of spreadsheets already exist?  Are you creating them programmatically?

Comment: They are all created and filled completely from code. Also, even though they have the same form, the columns and rows are filled in dynamically. So the "protected range" also will have to be dynamic.

I guess this is a huge letdown. I always brag and defend google all the time to peers and professors. This small thing is really unforgivable with google's standards.

Thanks for the confirmation. Is that google group the only place to voice our concern? I feel like this is a easy fix and it is just the fact that a top coder at google hasn't seen our complaints, the reason nothing has been done.

Comment: Bummer - yeah, they can be pretty slow to roll out important parts of their API.  There's a partial workaround using data validation rules, which can be set programmatically for any range of cells using [`Range.setDataValidations(rules)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setDataValidations(DataValidation)).  Here's where [a guy describes it](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/z8izMNhS1jE/8YuwVrvFiKwJ). It's only a protection against clumsy mistakes, not malice, but maybe it'll do for you until Google rolls out the cell protection API.

Comment: I'll give this a try. If it doesn't work for me, then I'll just wait it out and have the Spreadsheets naked and warn the users to not f**k up. :) Thanks for all the info!

Comment: Now there is a [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) : `var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');`

Answer (score 1):

Part of your question asked about protecting a sheet. Please have a look here: [setProtected(protection)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/page-protection#setProtected%28Boolean%29)

As for programmatically protecting a range no. However, you could protect a sheet, does not need to be in the same spreadsheet and then create an onEdit trigger that would replace any change in your "protected" range with the original source data.

Something like this:

```
function onLoad() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var protected = ss.getSheets()[1].getRange("A1:B2").getValues(); //You could use openByID to get from a different ss
  var target = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1:B2").setValues(protected);
}

function onEdit(){ 
 onLoad();
}
```

Every time a change is made to the spreadsheet the script will rewrite the data in the sheet for the range you specify.

Comment: This would work if this is for myself. But once I make these, they are being emailed to people that will be using them. And having duplicates of all the hundreds of Spreadsheets, that have probably around 4-7 sheets inside them, will get real ugly, real fast. I guess I just have to work without protections of ranges and send an email saying to be extra careful not to mess with cells that aren't suppose to be messed with. Thanks, though!

Comment: You can keep one Spreadsheet with your default values and have the script that sends with all the other copies reference that sheet.
var protected = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YOURMASTERID').getSheets()[1].getRange("A1:B2").getValues();

Comment: PagePortection is now deprecated. See my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/30210607/974389.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach I've found is to use Data Validation: that is, write a script which will examine each cell to be 'protected' and create and apply a validation rule which enforces entry of the existing content and rejects anything else. [Of course, this also implies that you have designed your spreadsheet such that all entered data is on sheet or sheets separate from those which have formula embedded. On these you use normal sheet protection.]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Control protected ranges and sheets in Google Sheets with Apps Script](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.mx/2015/02/control-protected-ranges-and-sheets-in.html), posted on February 19, 2015, now is possible to protect a Google Sheets range.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection

> Class Protection
>
> Access and modify protected ranges and sheets. A protected range can
>   protect either a static range of cells or a named range. A protected
>   sheet may include unprotected regions. For spreadsheets created with
>   the older version of Google Sheets, use the [<strike>PageProtection class</strike>](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/page-protection.html)
>   instead.
>
> ```
>  // Protect range A1:B10, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
>  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
>  var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
>  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
>
>  // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
>  // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
>  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
>  protection.addEditor(me);
>  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
>  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
>    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending 100s of copies of the same sheet.  Then create a template sheet, protect the ranges in it manually and send a copy of the template.  It will retain the protection.

Sorry but as others have said there is not script method of setting protection at a sub-sheet level.